# Alfresco Share webscripts all give "Cannot locate template processor for template ..." error

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I tried the "Hello World" webscript tutorial and that gives me a 500 error (details below) not being able to find the appropriate template processor. Thinking this was just a random occurence, I tried other webscripts. enable-site.get.js (from Martin Bergljung's blog) used to work, and now doesn't. create-site.post.js gives me an error with not being able to assign fields in the model to the view; all fairly consistent with view issues. In fact all the get share tier scripts also give the "Cannot locate template processor for template..."

I'm not aware that I've changed anything; however I don't understand why certain webscripts that came with alfresco (create-site.post for example) don't work out of the box. My guess is that I've done something incorrect with setting up my alfresco server; however I've no idea what that would be. If anyone has had similar symptoms then it would be great to hear a resolution.

Error as follows:

```
The Web Script /alfresco/service/helloworld has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description:    An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Message:    07050003 Cannot locate template processor for template helloworld.get.html

Exception:  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 07050003 Cannot locate template processor for template helloworld.get.html
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.renderTemplate(AbstractWebScript.java:904)
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.renderFormatTemplate(DeclarativeWebScript.java:267)
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:147)
    org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:377)
    org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
    org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:268)
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Server: Community v4.2.0 (r63893-b12) schema 6,033
Time:   05-Aug-2014 17:17:04
```

Comment: Where and how have you defined your ftl?

Comment: Error is simply because alfresco not able to find respective ftl file for webscript. So check exact location of ftl, check for typo in name or.

Comment: @mardoz /opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/modules. At the moment none of the ftls can be found for any of the share tier config scripts. The issue is that th ftl files are with the js webscripts (where I understand they are meant to be) but none can be found. This is how alfresco arrived OOTB, and so since alfresco is clearly not junk software (and works very well) I can assume it's a setting I've got wrong or something else.

Comment: Are there any errors during startup or server bootstrap? Also, what edition are you actually using? For 'server' it says Community v4.2.0 which isn't a version number for Community edition.

Comment: @Mardoz 4.2.e. But that's the error as pasted.

Comment: @DavidBoshton: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @SorinPostelnicu Yes and no, hence I've not posted it. I have found that webscripts at the share layer sometimes give this error if you don't send in a decoded alfresco CSRF token as header when using cURL or python requests, amongst other issues. This issue was latent on the web interface itself. I've just worked it out -- I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with how I was running the webscript. I was running it by clicking on it on the webscripts index page, which is accessible from the repo layer. Why is this important? Because the share and repo layers use different authentication methods. Share requires a decoded recent CSRF token and cookie to be added in along with 4 cookies,`Alfresco-CSRFToken`, `JSESSIONID`, `alfLogin` and `alfUsername3`. If these are not all present, you can get a plethora of errors which are not always what you expect. For example, when using `create-site` I've had the above error on an out of the box installation of Alfresco (which, if you don't know, comes with that webscript built in!) as well as a `duplicate shortName` (site UID) error on a name that I have demonstrated to be unique by listing all the current sites and it not being there.

So the errors I had would have been due to my browser not having the appropriate authentication cookies, or not passing them over correctly. This can be easily checked using Chromium's developer tools or Firebug. When the authentication is correct for share, everything works as expected. I now have a python wrapper that does it all for me (which I really should put on github!)

Comment: Super! I added the ticket to the url (generated with java class used to authenticate into Alfresco from my application) and it works. So, I confirm, it's a browser authentication "problem".